# linux-arm page fault handler and detecting originating thread

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, armv7

For a project with specific hardware integration, we need to modify the linux kernel's page_fault handler and I wondered if the following is possible:

1) during the do_page_fault, can we know which thread generated that fault (thread and process). the platform is ARM so arm-specific interrupt registers can be used if helpful

2) can we access the user-space memory of that process and read some information that our user-mode library left us prior to that? (assuming it's already probed and locked in memory)

Further explanation in the comment, if one desires.

Comment: (from the limits of what we can expose, suppose we'll need to page in some data of our own from at realtime so we'll have page_fault handler that will implement our hardware integration (not network).  To save some at kernel time for asynchronous meta-data calculations, our user-mode library loaded into the application will feed us with some meta data (which is not a must if not exist).
and so we need to reach it during that fault handler.
For performance considerations, we cannot use the normal path of user->kernel entrance (ioctl / escape / sysfs and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ 1): If the page fault happened while accessing memory from the userspace application (which is likely), then the page fault handler runs in the context of that process. From CPU point of view it enters kernel mode because of exception from MMU. So yes, you can get pid/tid of the userspace process that was interrupted..

@ 2): Yes. Kernel can access all the memory. If it's a 32bit system you need Highmem support, if it's a 64bit then you get it out of the box.

Comment: BTW, as for 1, will the process of determine the current pid/tid be heavy? (i.e : retrieving it from the os) or will it sit in the registers / backed-up registers?    (In practice what i need is to access meta data our usermode lib left our driver the tls of that thread... so if that could be achieve in a more simpler way we don't really care of the actual tid/pid)

Comment: In Kernel space, retrieving the pid is just a matter of reading "current->pid" value. Check out "The Current Process" chapter [here](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch02.html).